# Clear Google Chrome Browsing Data keyboard shortcut without confirmation prompt

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

On Mac OS X 10.6, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>....wonderful. Except I have to wait for a new tab to open and click to confirm. Is there a keyboard shortcut to clear it with last used settings, no confirmation needed?

If there isn't a built-in way to do this, is there a hack that can accomplish it? I am looking for a one-stroke shortcut to clear the parts of history I choose to clear.

I want my browser to preserve state across sessions if I don't force it to clear.

How can I clear history with a keyboard shortcut?